# Objective c: code for lanscaperight and landscapeleft

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ipad, orientation, landscape

I am creating an iPad, I would like to have only two orientations: lanscape right and left (not portrait) ... I have already changed. plist file but what should I write in code?

`- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) {interfaceOrientation
         return??
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this method:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
     return interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft);
}
```

There is also a convenience function that you can utilize if you wish to keep it a bit cleaner:

```
return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
```